# How do I bind an object method to its context if the object method is passed to a function as an argument

Tags: javascript, this, apply, call, bind

I have an object with a method that I want to pass to a special function. The job of this special function is to call the function passed as an argument and also to save all the arguments passed to the executed/returned/called function to an external variable.

```
const playerPerformance = {
  goals: 18,
  assists: 19,
  total(penalties, tackles) {
    return this.goals + this.assists + penalties + tackles;
  },
};

const calls = [];

function saveCalls(func) {
  return withMemory = (...rest) => {
    calls.push(rest);
    return func(...rest);
    };
  };

const tester = saveCalls(playerPerformance.total);
```

The problem is that I do not know how to save the context of the passed function. It must be done inside the function `saveCalls`, not like this `const tester = saveCalls(playerPerformance.total.bind(playerPerformance);`. I tried applying the methods `bind(), call(), apply()` inside `saveCalls` but this does not work this way.

The current result:

```
tester(2,1) // NaN
```

...which is understandable as I lose a context, and I get `undefined + undefined + 2 + 1`

The wanted result after this code change:

```
tester(2,1) // 40
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make a wrapper function, that makes provides right `this` argument to `total`. The `bind` method is designed for this:

```
const tester = saveCalls(playerPerformance.total.bind(playerPerformance));
```